# How to record using phone microphone on browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, recording

I am trying to record a voice from browsers but it only works on chrome browser in my mac but the same  doesn't work in any other browser. My goal is to record the voice from a phone from a browser.

I have been trying this below example but it doesn't works on mobile browsers. It opens up the microphone but doesn't stop recording and never plays it back.

I think the problem is somewhere around recorder.stop() which doesn't get called.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</head>

<body>
 <audio controls autoplay></audio>
<script type="text/javascript" src="recorder.js"> </script>

<input onclick="startRecording()" type="button" value="start recording" />
<input onclick="stopRecording()" type="button" value="stop recording and play" />

<script>
  var onFail = function(e) {
    console.log('Rejected!', e);
  };

  var onSuccess = function(s) {
    var context = new webkitAudioContext();
    var mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(s);
    recorder = new Recorder(mediaStreamSource);
    recorder.record();

    // audio loopback
    // mediaStreamSource.connect(context.destination);
  }

  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

  var recorder;
  var audio = document.querySelector('audio');

  function startRecording() {
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, onSuccess, onFail);
    } else {
      console.log('navigator.getUserMedia not present');
    }
  }

  function stopRecording() {
    //alert("hello");
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
      //audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(s);

      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    audio.src = url;
                    audio.controls = true;
                    var hf = document.createElement('a');
                    hf.href = url;
                    hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
                    //upload(blob);   
                    audio.src = url;
    });

  }

  function upload(blobOrFile) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload.aspx', true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        var result = e.target.result;
  };

    xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For `AudioContext` you are using the `webkit` prefix. This means that it will only work in certain `webkit` browsers. You probably want to check the existence of `AudioContext`, `webkitAudioContext`, `mozAudioContext`, etc and then choose the one that exists, if any. However, a quick check on [_MDN_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext#Browser_compatibility) shows that _Chrome_ is the only one with it available

Answer (score 1):

Only Chrome supports as of now the AudioContext interface.
Firefox also has an implementation but only in the Nightly build.

I'm not sure if it is supported by the mobile version of these browsers.