# WebRTC: Get audio level of a mediaStream *without* playing back the audio

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc

I'm looking to get the microphone activity level of a WebRTC MediaStream. However, I need to get this information **without** playing back the microphone to the user (otherwise there will be the loopback effect).

The answer in [Microphone activity level of WebRTC MediaStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724414/microphone-activity-level-of-webrtc-mediastream) relies on the audio being played back to the user. How can I do this, without playing back the microphone?

Comment: No it does not? I just tested the code and the mediastream simply goes into the node and is never played back to the speakers. I believe you HAVE to do with with the AudioAPI and connecting it to a node is not playing the audio back...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [`createGain` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createGain). It allows you to set stream's volume.

Here is my (simplified) example that I use in my project:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
    var audioContext = new AudioContext; //or webkitAudioContext
    var source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    var volume = audioContext.createGain();
    source.connect(volume);
    volume.connect(audioContext.destination);
    volume.gain.value = 0;  //turn off the speakers

    //further manipulations with source
}, function(err) {
    console.log('error', err);
});
```